# 301 redirect with url parameters

Tags: .htaccess

To keep google ranking i need to relink for exemple

```
Redirect 301 /kataloger.asp?id=1 http://www.domain.se/kataloger/category/kopplingar
Redirect 301 /kataloger.asp?id=2 http://www.domain.se/kataloger/category/ventiler
```

and in others ignore all but the id

```
Redirect 301 /produkter.asp?id=15 http://www.domain.se/produkter/kopplingar/a-lok-kopplingar/
Redirect 301 /produkter.asp?id=15&l=3 http://www.domain.se/produkter/kopplingar/a-lok-kopplingar/
Redirect 301 /produkter.asp?id=15&l=4 http://www.domain.se/produkter/kopplingar/a-lok-kopplingar/
```

But they all relink to /kataloger/ and /produkter/ and additionally throw a 404 att google.
What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [How to 301 redirect old urls with query strings](https://ellislab.com/forums/archive/viewthread/223483/)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1$
RewriteRule (kataloger.*) /kataloger/category/kopplingar? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=15&(.+)$
RewriteRule (produkter.*) /produkter/kopplingar/a-lok-kopplingar/? [R=301,L]
```